# WP7 - Call bound number on clicking Listbox item

Tags: listbox, windows-phone-7

So I have a list of objects containing a name and number bound to a listbox in XAML. The listbox displays the number fine, but I want it to call the phone number using phonecall on click. Here is the onlick code:

```
    private void taxiListItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.PhoneCallTask phonecall = new Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.PhoneCallTask();
        phonecall.PhoneNumber = "213";
        phonecall.Show();
    }
```

and here is where I define the TaxiCompany object that populates the list.

```
    public class TaxiCompany {
        public String CoName { get; set; }
        public String Phone { get; set; }
        public TaxiCompany(String coname, String phone) {
            this.CoName = coname;
            this.Phone = phone;

        }
    }
```

The phone call works fine when I hardcode the number . Now, when I set phonecall.Phonenumber = sender.getPhone() or e.Phone() or any variant of the two, its marked as an undefined method. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here? I assume object sender or e is the list item being clicked on.

Note: the listbox in the XAML displays both the phone number and address just fine

```
                   <Button Click="taxiListItem_Click" Width ="436" Height="120">
                        <Button.Content>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height=" 80">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="40" Width="436">
                                <TextBlock Width="436" FontSize="30" Text= "{Binding CoName}" Height="40"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="40" Width="436">
                                <TextBlock Name ="PhoneNo"  Width="300" FontSize="22" Text= "{Binding Phone}" Height="40"/>
                            </StackPanel>

                            </StackPanel>    
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
```

First time working with C# / Silverlight so any help would be apprecaited.

Comment: How does your button relate to your listbox?

Comment: i use a {Binding} - is that what you were asking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. The listbox shows the taxi companies and selecting an item in the list causes the phone numbe rot try and be dialed.

Notice that it's not necessary to add buttons to the list and that it's necessary to cast the variables passed to the selection event. (Could also cast the sender to a listbox and then cast the selected item.)

xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="MainListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding TaxiCompanies}" SelectionChanged="MainListBox_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height=" 80">
                <TextBlock Width="436" FontSize="30" Text= "{Binding CoName}" Height="40"/>
                <TextBlock Name ="PhoneNo"  Width="300" FontSize="22" Text= "{Binding Phone}" Height="40"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

cs:

```
// class used for example. Another name would be more appropriate
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<TaxiCompany> TaxiCompanies { get; private set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        TaxiCompanies = new ObservableCollection<TaxiCompany>();
        TaxiCompanies.Add(new TaxiCompany("AAA Cabs", "123-456-789"));
        TaxiCompanies.Add(new TaxiCompany("BBB Taxis", "111234329"));
        TaxiCompanies.Add(new TaxiCompany("CCC Cars", "98765432"));
    }
}

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set the data context of the listbox control to the sample data
        DataContext = new ViewModel();

        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
    }

    private void MainListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var phonecall = new PhoneCallTask();
        phonecall.PhoneNumber = ((TaxiCompany)(((object[])(e.AddedItems))[0])).Phone;
        phonecall.Show();

        // Reset selected index to -1 (no selection)
        MainListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

Comment: thanks! this MainListBox.SelectedIndex = -1; statement kept causing it to crash though, when I commented it out it was fine

Comment: I would upvote your answer, but I don't have the reputation :(